# How to Fix Http: Unauthorized Error in C#?

Tags: c#

I have C# code to receive data from Server and store this data in CSV files, after the program running for 7-10 hours the program stop working after gives me this error many times.

Error:

```
HTTP: Unauthorized
{"code":401,"message":"Authentication missing or invalid.","type":"UnauthorizedError"}
```

note:-
the program was working well for 1 month without any stop, but nowadays I don't know what is going on.

Comment: Uh, unauthorized means unauthorized. The server seems to require authentication.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some code to your question, so we can better understand your question and possibly identify the issue(s). It is recommended to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please explain what your accessing with your HTTP Request, is it an external source or something you developed/local source?

Comment: Some one put authentication on server, and did not tell you.

Comment: @Aya, can you provide more details of the environment and technology you are using?

Comment: @Aya If you're using access tokens, do you also get a refresh token? I imagine that you're using some kind of token-based authentication and that the token you're using to authenticate yourself expires. A code example would really help here (see [mcve])

Comment: @ john Yes I am refreshing the access token every 1 hour, and I am using Real-time data request.

Comment: Are you providing valid credentials to get the data from the server?

Comment: Try using a IE and delete cookies and see if the application starts working again.  You probably either have a cookies that time has expired or the server still thinks you are logged in and doesn't allow multiple connections from the same client.  Deleting the cookies will make the server recognize you application as a new client instead of an existing client.

Comment: @ jdweng I have deleted the cookies but the problem still.